How to add Space on the top for all print pages using html and css
First Page
Second Page
Actually I am converting html to PDF using Node JS. PDF also successfully generated but when it comes to PDF  multiple pages not properly showing. I tried to add header and table to all pages but it's overlapping. How to fix this Issue. I tried a lot of solutions but it's not working.
I applied this css :
@media print {
   thead {
      display: table-header-group;
   }

   tr.page-break {
      page-break-before: always;
   }

   }
.header-section-0 {
    display: grid;
    position: fixed;
    top: 34px;
    left: 76px;
    right: 79px;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 1000;
 }`


Try one of those two instructions, or two of them (changing the place where page-break is used) :
tr.page-break {
  page-break-inside: avoid; 
  page-break-after: auto;
}

And I'm not sure using "grid" is a wonderful solution.
